# If function with looping to create new datatable

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset which i want to loop over with an if function:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
value1 <- c(25, 100, 15, 20, 30)
value2 <- c(130, 25, 10, 30, 20)
value3 <- c(50, 60, 20, 120, 10)
month <- c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3)
df1 <- dataframe(id,value1, value2, value3, month)
```

I need an if function that would calculate the differences between value 1 and 2 and between 1 and 3 and check if one OR the other is higher than 35%. This should not be the change(increase or decrease) but just the difference in percentages. And when the differences is equal or higher than 35% it should add all the variables for that specific id to a seperate dataframe/table.

However i the function to loop over all the id's instead of just the top one.

This is what i have so far:

```
library(threadr)
if (percentage_difference(value1, value2) >= 35 | percentage_difference(value1, value3) >= 35) {print "bad"}
```

Comment: Percentage difference as in abs(value1 - value2) / 100 >= 35? With the specified values you won't reach that, or just abs(value1 - value2) / 100 >= 0.35? "when the differences is equal or higher than 35% it should add all the variables for that specific id to a seperate dataframe/table". Do you mean all the rows in the df corresponding to the id?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i would like @tavdp

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick, though I am not sure how you would want to indicate if it is >35.

Here I used a boolean T/F:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1
df2$perc_diff <- pmax(value1-value2, value1-value3)
df2$over35 <- df2$perc_diff >= 35


# id value1 value2 value3 month perc_diff over35
# 1  1     25    130     50     2       -25  FALSE
# 2  2    100     25     60     3        75   TRUE
# 3  3     15     10     20     4         5  FALSE
# 4  4     20     30    120     2       -10  FALSE
# 5  5     30     20     10     3        20  FALSE
```

Here I removed those < 35:

```
df3 <- df1
df3$perc_diff <- pmax(value1-value2, value1-value3)
df3[df3$perc_diff >= 35,]

#  id value1 value2 value3 month perc_diff
#  2    100     25     60     3        75
```

Comment: how would i go about adding more values (valueX)? because i tried adding more and it gave back this error: argument is missing, with no default
Because i also want to compare 2 and 3

Comment: Do you mean value1 vs valueX? Perhaps `pmax(value1-value2, value1-value3, value1-valueX)` - the function `pmax` takes the maximum of the imported values by row.

Comment: turns out i just put a comma too much. However i would like to ask if your code takes in account that value1 etc are not percentages yet?

Comment: Based on your description, I assumed `value` variables were percentages - I tried to answer the question verbatim: "calculate differences between value 1 and 2 and between 1 and 3 and check if one OR the other is higher than 35%"

Comment: it helped out a lot anyway sorry for my unclear post